# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found _ on a different machine (pyinstaller)

Tags: python, database, db2, websphere, pyinstaller

I was able to get exe file from py using pyinstaller.
I used the following code:

```
pyinstaller -y -F --additional-hooks-dir=. --add-binary ibm_db_dlls;.\ibm_db_dlls Data_QC_Ver1.py
```

this work fine on my laptop, however when trying it on a different machine I get the following error:
[image: error showing on the other machine]

Comment: Try running your cmd as administrator.

Comment: same thing, no change

Comment: Maybe try using auto-py-to-exe?

Comment: What is auto-py-to-exe?

Comment: It is an application installed through PIP which allows a user to convert py files to executable files. It has a GUI and has very simple commands to open so it is hard to receive errors. Would you like me to answer the question and add the resources I use to help you use it?

Comment: yes, please. go ahead

Comment: I have answered your question